# Generic comparer using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, comparison

I am putting together simple generic comparer for unit testing.
I don't want to use IComparable interface because there is just too much classes that would need to implement it, and it will be only used in Unit tests so performance of reflection is not an issue.

So far I have this:

```
 public IEnumerable<NonEqualProperty> Compare<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
        {
            var list = new List<NonEqualProperty>();
            var type = first.GetType();
            var properties = type.GetProperties();

            var basicTypes = properties.Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsClass && !p.PropertyType.IsInterface
                                                   || p.PropertyType == typeof(string));


            foreach (var prop in basicTypes)
            {
                var value1 = prop.GetValue(first, null);
                var value2 = prop.GetValue(second, null);

                if (value1 != null && value2 != null && value1.Equals(value2) || value1 == null && value2 == null )
                    continue;

                list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name, value1, value2));
            }

            var enumerableTypes =
                from prop in properties
                from interfaceType in prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()
                where interfaceType.IsGenericType
                let baseInterface = interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                where prop.PropertyType != typeof(string) && baseInterface == typeof(IEnumerable<>) || baseInterface == typeof(IEnumerable)
                select prop;

            foreach (var prop in enumerableTypes)
            {
                var collection = prop.GetValue(first, null);
            }


            return list;
        }
```

So comparison of all simple types + string works.

Now I would like to iterate through IEnumerable (it's always enumerable of a class, though it would be great to take care of the case when it's not) on both sides and compare values using recursion. Something like this:

```
foreach (var prop in enumerableTypes)
{
    var typeOfItemsInList= ...;
    var collection1 = (IEnumerable<typeOfItemsInList>) prop.GetValue(first, null);
    var collection2 = (IEnumerable<typeOfItemsInList>) prop.GetValue(second, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < collection1.Count; i++)
    {
        var item1 = collection1[i];
        var item2 = collection2[i];

        Compare<typeOfItemsInList>(item1, item2, list);
    }

}
```

How would I achieve that?

Unequal count, or order of items in lists are not taken into account here - I would fix it later.

Comment: While I don't have time to look at your question, I've worked with such a comparer before and would like to add this: Don't forget Nullable types (e.g. int?) and that dates, and floating point numbers, etc. can fail comparison due to differences in storage mechanisms and rounding errors. They'll come around and surprise you at some point otherwise :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why not just use a testing library such as NUnit? It provides the functionality you're looking for, and so much more.

Comment: Don't use the `IEnumerable<typeOfItemsInList>`, use the base `IEnumerable` non-generic type. It is much easier.

Comment: @mireigi could you provide me with a link/name to that specific component/class of NUnit that can do it? I've never used NUnit but maybe I'll try it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<NonEqualProperty> Compare<T>(T first, T second) where T : class {
    var list = new List<NonEqualProperty>();
    var type = first.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    var basicTypes = properties.Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsClass && !p.PropertyType.IsInterface
                                            || p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    foreach (var prop in basicTypes) {
        var value1 = prop.GetValue(first, null);
        var value2 = prop.GetValue(second, null);

        if (object.Equals(value1, value2))
            continue;

        list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name, value1, value2));
    }

    var enumerableTypes =
        from prop in properties
        where prop.PropertyType == typeof(IEnumerable) ||
            prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable))
        select prop;

    foreach (var prop in enumerableTypes) {
        var value1 = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(first, null);
        var value2 = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(second, null);

        if (object.Equals(value1, value2))
            continue;

        if (value1 == null || value2 == null) {
            list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name, value1, value2));
            continue;
        }

        IEnumerator enu1 = null, enu2 = null;

        try {
            try {
                enu1 = value1.GetEnumerator();
                enu2 = value2.GetEnumerator();

                int ix = -1;

                while (true) {
                    bool next1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                    bool next2 = enu2.MoveNext();
                    ix++;

                    if (!next1) {
                        while (next2) {
                            list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name + "_" + ix, "MISSING", enu2.Current));
                            ix++;
                            next2 = enu2.MoveNext();
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    if (!next2) {
                        while (next1) {
                            list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name + "_" + ix, enu1.Current, "MISSING"));
                            ix++;
                            next1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    if (enu1.Current != null) {
                        var type1 = enu1.Current.GetType();

                        if ((type1.IsClass || type1.IsInterface) && type1 != typeof(string)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (enu2.Current != null) {
                        var type2 = enu2.Current.GetType();

                        if ((type2.IsClass || type2.IsInterface) && type2 != typeof(string)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!object.Equals(enu1.Current, enu2.Current)) {
                        list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name + "_" + ix, enu1.Current, enu2.Current));
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                var disp2 = enu2 as IDisposable;

                if (disp2 != null) {
                    disp2.Dispose();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            var disp1 = enu1 as IDisposable;

            if (disp1 != null) {
                disp1.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I'm using the `IEnumerable` non-generic interface. Note that I'm doing the type-test on each element.

To not change the `NonEqualProperty` class I'm saving the `ix` of the difference directly in the `prop.Name` (so like `SomeCollection_0`, `SomeCollection_1` if the different elements are 0 and 1). Normally I would add an `Index` property to `NonEqualProperty` For the "missing" elements I'm using a `"MISSING"` string, that is ok if you want to take a look at it with the debugger, but there are better ways to do it (add another property "Missing" to `NonEqualProperty` for example, or do a

```
 public static readonly object Missing = new object();
```

and use it for missing values.

There are other ways without using the `IEnumerable` interface, like a:

```
private static IEnumerable<NonEqualProperty> CompareCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> firstColl, IEnumerable<T> secondColl) {
    var list = new List<NonEqualProperty>();

    // Do the comparison

    return list;
}

private static MethodInfo CompareCollectionMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CompareCollection", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

and then

```
    var value1 = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(first, null);
    var value2 = (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(second, null);

    if (object.Equals(value1, value2))
        continue;

    if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(IEnumerable)) {
        var ienumt = prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ienumt != null) {
            var t = ienumt.GetGenericArguments(); // T of IEnumerable<T>

            if ((t[0].IsClass || t[0].IsInterface) && t[0] != typeof(string)) {
                continue;
            }

            var method = CompareCollectionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t);
            var result = (IEnumerable<NonEqualProperty>)method.Invoke(null, new[] { value1, value2 });
            list.AddRange(result);
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (value1 == null || value2 == null) {
        list.Add(new NonEqualProperty(prop.Name, value1, value2));
        continue;
    }

    // continue with the code for non-generic IEnumerable

    IEnumerator enu1 = null, enu2 = null;
```

Comment: Looks promising :) - I'm gonna have to take a closer look though.

Comment: Alright.. after a few tweaks it should be just what I need, thanks :)